# boxplot labels with greek characters and subscripts

Tags: matlab, label, matlab-figure, boxplot

```
A = rand(10,2);
boxplot(A,'labels',{'N(\mu_{p},\sigma_{p})_{F}','N_{a}'})
```

For this I was expecting the x-axis to have N(mu_p, sigma_p)_F, with Latin characters for mu and sigma and subscript for p and F. But neither the subscript nor the Latin characters worked. Any suggestion?

Comment: When adding 'interpreter','latex' , I get the following error message: Error using boxplot>parseArgs (line 547) Invalid parameter name: interpreter.

Comment: Is it not what you're looking for?

Comment: Just rewrote the question and made two columns, since this needs to be XTickLabel and not xlabel

Comment: It does not. just rewrote the question and made two columns instead of one. This needs to be XTickLabel and not xlabel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that works:

```
A = rand(10,2);
boxplot(A,'labels',{'$$N(\mu_{p},\sigma_{p})_{F}$$','$$N_{a}$$'});
bp = gca;
bp.XAxis.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex';
```

[image: bp greek]

Answer (score 2):

Set the label separately and use the **latex interpreter**:

```
A = rand(10,1);
b = boxplot(A);
xlabel({'$$N(\mu_{p},\sigma_{p})_{F}$$'},'interpreter','latex')
```

---

[image]

Comment: This does not. just rewrote the question and made two columns instead of one. This needs to be XTickLabel and not xlabel

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same problem - the (non)solution appears to be that you can't have non-standard characters for tick labels. This is due to the [labels not being considered text objects](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/36645) in MATLAB.

There are some work-arounds. One example was to turn off the tick labels and then insert your own text objects in place of the labels. This can be done through the Figure GUI.